# Need help finding which script Python runs on startup

Tags: python, initialization, lazy-loading

I'm trying to find which Python script loads whenever python is first run. For example, if you run `python -v`, you see some output like:

```
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
import site # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/site.pyo
import os # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/os.pyo
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
import posixpath # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyo
import stat # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/stat.pyo
import genericpath # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyo
import warnings # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/warnings.pyo
import linecache # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/linecache.pyo
import types # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/types.pyo
import UserDict # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyo
import _abcoll # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyo
import abc # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/abc.pyo
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyo
import _weakref # builtin
import copy_reg # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyo
import traceback # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/traceback.pyo
import sysconfig # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyo
import re # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/re.pyo
import sre_compile # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyo
import _sre # builtin
import sre_parse # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyo
import sre_constants # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyo
import _sysconfigdata # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyo
import encodings # directory /lib/python2.7/encodings
import encodings # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyo
import codecs # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/codecs.pyo
import _codecs # builtin
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyo
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyo
```

I want to find the script that is running these commands, in order to lazy load some of the modules for use when running in a low memory environment.
I think it might be built into `libpython2.7.a` which makes it difficult to lazy load.
I have found that alot of these modules are object files such as

```
posixmodule.o errnomodule.o  pwdmodule.o  _sre.o  _codecsmodule.o  _weakref.o  zipimport.o  symtablemodule.o  xxsubtype.o
```

Which then gets compiled to produce the final `libpython2.7.a`.

What I would like is some place in the source, perhaps even before building it, where I can replace:

`import linecache`

or whichever the imports that can be deferred after loading, to

`linecache = lazy_import.lazy_module("linecache")`.

Does anyone know where/if this script is in the Python source code?
Thanks

Comment: who says this is done with a script, maybe it is hard coded and the loader prints some `import` message

Comment: have you looked at MicroPython

Comment: Yes maybe it is, that will make it alot more difficult. I have looked at MicroPython, which has its own set of hurdles, which I would try after I am certain I can't achieve < 200MB memory loading on initializing with vanilla Python.

Comment: In a completely clean environment, the only script that runs on startup is `site.py`. You can skip that from being loaded, but then you have to do quite a bit of init work yourself.

Comment: But I am also pretty sure that lazy loading most of those modules will not do anything, since `site` (or python itself) imports them to then actually use them immediately, not just for the future.

Comment: @MegaIng Oh okay, so I am assuming `os` and `sys` still work with `python -S` without needing `site`? I'm just after a way to defer that initial 200MB memory bump since it is too much for an embedded environment, but I don't necessarily want to make Python unusable, do you know a way to span this import out, because as you imply, importing 200MB all at once at a later time is not going to work either.

Comment: For an embedded system, you definitely want to use micropython. What do you mean with "span this import out". You can't partially import a module. You can check the sourcecode of `site.py`, it does quite a bit of stuff, a lot of it probably not useful on an embedded system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably after loading Python without [`site`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html)

```bash
python -S
```

You might also be interested in [`-s` (lowercase)](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-s), which the subset of `USER_SITE` packages

Comment: Hi, that actually looks pretty close to what I am looking for. Ideally, I would still load site packages lazily, in the case that it becomes unusable without manually including these imports. I guess there is no easy solution until [PEP 690](https://peps.python.org/pep-0690/), ie `python -L`  is tabled.  I will have a look at this, thank you.

Comment: @tok1n "lazy loading" site doesn't make sense. site's only (or at least primary) purpose is to do a lot of config of the global interpreter state.